# symfony 2.8 phpunit default test returning failed

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit, default

I have following default test in PHPUnit and it is returning failed. I have accessed the path from the browser and it is displaying fine.

```
class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/hello/Fabien');

        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Hello Fabien")')->count() > 0);
    }
}
```

config_test.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        enabled: true # we want the profiler service to be defined
        collect: false

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
```

Comment: Have you checked `var/logs/tst.log` to see that it's getting the correct route and there are no other errors? Also, can you try `$this->assertContains('Hello Fabien',$client->getResponse()->getContent());` to see if that works. If it does, you will have to modify the filter based on the content.

Comment: What is the command you're using to execute the unittest ?

Comment: I needed to execute the unit tests with this command ```phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist``` to get them running without errors.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @AlvinBunk after checking `logs/tests.log`. The error was coming from translation messages, few messages didn't had opening and closing quote, after adding that it is displaying success message now.  Thank you

Comment: Should I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: If you want to, I have posted as answer too, but I'll accept yours if you post.

Answer (score 0):

after checking `logs/tests.log`. The error was coming from translation messages, few messages didn't have opening and closing quote, after adding that it is displaying success message now.